# Opening Outlook with Python

Tags: python, win32com

I am trying to open Outlook with Python and I got this...

```
import win32com.client
ol = win32com.client.Dispatch("outlook.Application")
```

It opens Outlook but my probles is it opens it in the notification area of Windows (where the clock is) and it doesn't open it up on the screen. I tried a ...

```
OL.visible= True
```

But I get an error that Outlook application can't be set to visible. So my question is how can I bring Outlook for, or maximze it to a full screen?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok I found this to work as simple as it was....

```
import os
os.startfile("outlook")
```

It makes it into a large window and mot a minimized one.

Comment: and how can you close it?

Comment: Is there an alternative in subprocess module that does the same? I tried a few. None worked.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914718/com-interop-outlook-make-outlook-visible)?  The solution there was to start up Outlook from a shell command and then attach to the running process.  It seems dirty, but I've done the same with other programs out of desperation.  I would expect MS Office to play nicer with COM.

I wonder if you could do something similar to the MS example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa210897%28v=office.11%29.aspx).

```
Set myOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set myNameSpace = myOlApp.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
Set myFolder= _
    myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
myFolder.Display
```

I don't have Outlook installed so I can't test anything.

Answer (score 0):

*You could also check if Outlook is running using [psutil](https://pypi.org/project/psutil/)*

```
import psutil

def is_outlook_running():
    for p in psutil.process_iter(attrs=['pid', 'name']):
        if "OUTLOOK.EXE" in p.info['name']:
            print("Yes", p.info['name'], "is running")
            break
    else:
        print("No, Outlook is not running")
        os.startfile("outlook")
        print("Outlook is starting now...")
```